# Solve The Differential Equation By Series Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How To Solve This Differential Equation By Series Solution
$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y = 0$

**My attempt:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y = 0$$
I suppose it's around $x=0$:
$$(1-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nn(n-1)x^{n-2}+2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nnx^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n} = 0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nn(n-1)x^{n-2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nn(n-1)x^{n}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nnx^{n}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n} = 0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nn(n-1)x^{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nnx^{n}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n} = 0$$
So that we have:
$$a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)=a_n(n^2-3n-2) $$
$$a_2=-a_0$$
$$3a_3+2a_1=0$$
So that your solution looks good to me. Now it's not going to be easy to find the recurrence formula and express the solution to the DE with elementary functions.

Comment: Is Equation 1 Right From My [Solution](https://imgur.com/a/PRMZJ9X) Because Wolfarm Alpha Shows Equation 2 As Answer.

Comment: Do you mean that equation 1 is wrong? If it is wrong so what can i do?